# How to implement a timer correctly?

Tags: java, timer

Ok i have this method to decrease my attribute  int sec(seconds) in my class  timer

```
private void decreaseSec(){

       if(sec <59  && sec > 0 ){
       sec--;}
       else if(sec == 0 && min == 0){
           sec = 0;
       }
       else if(sec == 0 && min > 0){
          sec = 59; 
          decreaseMin();
       }

   }
```

According to my logic its supose to correctly decrease the seconds.
But when it reach 0, starts counting to negative numbers(-1, -2, -3...)
I dont get it! Maybe some one could help me, or give a better way of doing it.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the seg variable for?

Comment: Why do you set `sec` to zero when it's already zero? Also, if `sec` is 59, why don't you want to decrement it?

Comment: I believe that's because his timer has finished and just wants it to stay at zero.

Comment: Could give more explanations (what is min, when is decrease sec called, what do decreaseMin()?...) or better, provide a SSCCE?

Comment: @rosscowar You don't have to set it to zero to make it stay at zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package Reloj;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author MarcoAntonio
 */
public class Temporizador {
    
     //Metodo estatico de mi aplicacion de AppLibreria
    public static void limpiaPantalla(){
        //Limpiando la pantalla
            for(int i = 0; i<25 ; i++){
                System.out.println();
            }    }
    
    private int hr;
   private int min;
   private int seg;
   
   
   public Temporizador (){
       
       hr  = min = seg = 0;
       
   }
   
   public Temporizador(int h, int m, int s){
       
       this();
       hr  = h;
       min = m;
       seg = s;
      
   }

    public void setHr(int hr) {
        this.hr = hr;
    }

    public void setMin(int min) {
        this.min = min;
    }

    public void setSeg(int seg) {
        this.seg = seg;
    }

    public int getHr() {
        return hr;
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public int getSeg() {
        return seg;
    } 
  
   public void decrementa(){
       if(hr == 0){
           if(min == 0 && seg != 0){
                  seg--;  
           }
           if(min != 0 && seg == 0){
               min--;
               seg = 59;
           }
           if(min != 0  && seg != 0){
               seg--;
           }
       }
       if(hr != 0){
           if(min == 0 && seg == 0){
               hr--;
               min = 59;
               seg = 59;
           }
           if(min == 0 && seg != 0){
                  seg--;  
           }
           if(min != 0 && seg == 0){
               min--;
               seg = 59;
           }
           if(min != 0  && seg != 0){
               seg--;
           }
           
       }
   }
   
   @ Override
   public String toString(){
       String tiempo = "";
       String ap;
       if(hr < 10){
           tiempo += "0" + hr + ":";         
       }
       else{
           tiempo += hr + ":";
       }
       if(min < 10){
           tiempo +="0" + min + ":";  
       }
       else{
           tiempo += min + ":";
       }
       if(seg < 10){
           tiempo +="0" + seg + " ";  
       }
       else{
           tiempo += seg + " ";
       }
            
       return tiempo;
   }
   
   public static void main(String args[]){
       
       boolean m = true;
       
       Temporizador t  = new Temporizador();
       Scanner       s = new Scanner(System.in);
       
       System.out.println("Buenas tardes...");
       System.out.println("Bienvenido al temporizador, a continuacion selecione las horas, minutos y segundo");
       System.out.println("para empezar la cuenta regresiva. P:");
       
           do{
       System.out.println("¿Cuantas horas?");
       int horas = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
       t.setHr(horas);
       
       System.out.println("¿Cuantos minutos?");
       int minutos = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
       t.setMin(minutos);
       
       System.out.println("¿Cuantos segundos?");
       int segundos = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
       t.setSeg(segundos);
       
       if( t.getHr() == 0 && t.getMin()== 0 && t.getSeg()==0 ){
          System.out.println("No inicializado su temporizador");
       
       limpiaPantalla();}
       
       }while(t.getHr() == 0 && t.getMin()== 0 && t.getSeg()==0);
            
         do{ 
             
             System.out.println(t.toString());
           t.decrementa();
           try{
               Thread.sleep(1);// un thread es una ejecucion en el procesador
           }catch(Exception e){}
           if(t.getHr() == 0 && t.getMin()== 0 && t.getSeg()==0){
               m = false;
           }
       }while( m != false);
         
      System.out.println("Listones! Tiempo finalizado");
       
       
   }
}
```

Its really easy to solve making a truth table of the diferents cases, we have 3 variables in binary are 8 combinations.

```
hr mn sg
0  0  0
0  0  1
0  1  0
0  1  1
1  0  0
1  0  1
1  1  0
1  1  1
```

The ones represent a numric value in the variables for example:

101 could be---- >  6hr  : 0' : 59''

Comment: Im open for any comment or suggestion P:

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You might be skipping over zero into your negative realm and never catching it.

```
private void decreaseSec(){

    if(sec > 0){
        sec--;
    }else if(sec <= 0 && min <= 0){
        sec = 0;
    }else if(sec <= 0 && min > 0){
       sec = 59; 
       decreaseMin();
    }

}
```